# Xcode 6.1 crashes when trying to 'Export for localization'

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I added localization to my project in Xcode 5.x and used the tools at hand at that time.

I have now added new strings and updated the storyboards so I need to update my translations. Therefore I tried to export my translation by using the menu "Editor | Export for localization...'. It brings up a dialog but when pressing Ok, Xcode presents an error for a second:

"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/extractLocStrings exited with status 1"

and then it crashes.

Any ideas why I cannot export the localization?

Answer (score 7):

I also had this problem and found that the easiest way to figure out which file is potentially the UTF-8 one if you have hundreds of files is to use the command line call:

```
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath <dirpath> -project <projectname> [[-exportLanguage <targetlanguage>]]
```

This will then give you a more helpful error:

Input file /path/to/your/file/filename.m cannot be read in UTF-8 encoding

```
xcodebuild: error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/extractLocStrings exited with status 1
```

Hope that helps others :)

Comment: Great, thanks. Just to clarify a few things:
The exported XLIFF files are placed in <dirpath>. -exportLanguage argument is optional.

Example:
xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath ./ -project YourApp.xcodeproj

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem: solved changing in a .m file the text enconding from western (Mac OS Roman) to UTF-8

Comment: Thanks. Apple has solved the problem (at least for me) in the latest update 6.1.1.